# jQuery hover flicker bug with IE 7/8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

As per the thread title, I am having a small problem with IE 7/8 where by when you hover over a thumbnail, it flickers. My code is as follows:-

```
function activateThumbnails(intThumbActiveOp, intThumbInActiveOp, intFadeTime,     strThumbClass)
{
    //Hide image title
    jQuery("a " + strThumbClass).attr('title', '');

    //Bind effect to post thumbnails..
    jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
        var activeOpacity   = intThumbActiveOp,
            inactiveOpacity = intThumbInActiveOp,
            fadeTime = intFadeTime,
            clickedClass = "selected",
            thumbs = strThumbClass;

        jQuery(thumbs).fadeTo(1, inactiveOpacity);

        //Animate thumbnail on hover event..
        jQuery(thumbs).hover(
            function(){
                //Fade into thumbnail..
                jQuery(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity, function(){
                    //Display Preview Body once faded in
                    intId = jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id'); //Get parent DIV ID
                    jQuery('#previewId' + intId.substr(6)).show();
                });
            },
            function(){
                // Only fade out if the user hasn't clicked the thumb
                if(!jQuery(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) 
                {
                    //Fade out of thumbnail..
                    jQuery(this).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity, function(){
                        //Hide Preview Body once faded out
                        intId = jQuery(this).closest('div').attr('id'); //Get parent DIV ID
                        jQuery('#previewId' + intId.substr(6)).hide();
                    });
                }
            });

        jQuery(thumbs).click(function() {
             // Remove selected class from any elements other than this
             var previous = jQuery(thumbs + '.' + clickedClass).eq();
             var clicked = jQuery(this);
             if(clicked !== previous) 
             {
                 previous.removeClass(clickedClass);
             }
             clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
         });
    });
 }
```

Please note I am laying some preview text over the hover images , and it is when the cursor is over the preview text (not the image itself) that you get the flicker in IE 7/8 only. This is illustrated by the fact the issue does not happen if there is no textual overlay.

Any help would be really much appreciated as I am on a tight deadline

Kind regards and thanks,

p.s here is my markup:

```
 <div id="postId" class="postContainer">
 <!-- Post Preview canvas -->
<div id="previewId" class='postPreview'>
    <!-- Post preview Title -->
    <div class="previewTitle">
        some title
    </div>
    <!-- Post preview Body -->
    <div class="previewBody">
        some text body
    </div>
</div>
<a href="#"> 
    some thumbnail
</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically the flicker is caused by you matching the hover over a character that moves out from under the mouse in the hovered state.  IE's wonderment trick is that "the background" between characters doesn't count as characters -- you actually have to be on a letter.  Consider wiring the hover to a div that contains this text and is sure not to move or get obscured in the hovered state.

Comment: Heya Robrich, thanks for your reply. I had considered putting the image (e.g. some thumbnail above) and the textual overlay (#previewid) in the same container, but this had the effect of the textual overlay being as faded as the image is in the hover state (I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It does make sense, and suggests that the css that makes it faded needs to be scoped more tightly.

Comment: Hi robrich, I have done as you said and this has had the desired effect - however in all browsers except IE the textual overlay is now being faded with the container. Ironicly all versions of IE are now working as I wanted! :)

Comment: Never mind I figured it out :  jQuery(this).children(":not('.previewTitle, .previewBody')").fadeTo()

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with flickering at the bottom of the treeview in Internet Explorer then make sure your document is of the type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN”
“http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd”>
<html xmlns=”http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml”>
```

When I used the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN”>
<html>
```

Internet Explorer 7 flickers the animation when that doctype is used. If
you don’t know what the flickering is causing then it could take a lot
of time to solve this problem :-)